# How to debug android app on galaxy tab

Tags: android

I am using galaxy tab for debugging my android app. But I am unable to get tab as the running device. USB is showing connected and I am using Mac OS. Could anyone help me to get rid from it?

Comment: are you able to solve your problem from my posted answer, if yes accept it please ?

Comment: Yeah.. Actually the USB setting was missed. I enabled the USB debugging and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto settings -->developer options and check the Usb debugging, remove and connect the cable

Answer (score 6):

Steps for USB debugging for galaxy tab are listed here.

1. Install Samsung kies on your development machine from http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP  after installling you might need to restart your machine.
2. Go to Device's Settings -> Developer Options and Enable USB Debugging.
3. Then Attach device USB cable with your machine(If its already attached , reattach it)

And you are all set for debugging now. have a good time with galaxy tab :)

Answer (score 3):

I followed the instructions above and still couldn't set developer options on my Tab 2 because I couldn't see the developer options on the settings menu. 
I am currently having trouble debugging on my note 2 (this is why I'm messing with the Tab) anyway I read in stack overflow pressing the Build number seven times to show the developer options - I didn't believe it but when I'd hunted all over for how to set up the developer options and couldn't find anything for the tab I thought I would give it a try.
I wouldn't have believed it if I didn't do it myself. So if you can't see the developer options press the build button seven times. After a couple of presses it even starts counting down.
I had long since moved away from the post where I read it but I owe that man a tick
So unbelievable but true - give it a go

Further to my original post I have since installed kies and now both devices work I think installing kies fixed my note2 issue and yes Munazza I accepted your answer as well

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I almost gave up trying to find the dang developer option. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: ha ha, i had a pop up message after tapping 3 times that I'm in just in 4 steps to become developer:) Thanks buddy, that was driving my nuts for couple days.

Comment: I wonder if it is specific easter egg for samsung or that's joke from Android team

Comment: That turns to be Android 4.2 feature

Answer (score 0):

You need to install drivers for USB debugging on device. for Samsung there is something called as samsung kies which i used on windows. It should be available for MAC as well. please check [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). Also you should enable USB debugging on device.